# String to variable

Tags: c#

I have a variable test..

```
String test = TextBox1.Text;
```

I want to know if the user enters into this variable 04151.

Comment: I think you might need to lookup some beginner C# tutorials...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with beginner questions.  Especially since it is a library question, essentially.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (test == "04151")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Yep!");
}
```

---

**Edit:**

```
if (test.Contains("04151"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Yep!");
}
```

Comment: if the user enters "Ex H 4 04151" 
how do I check?

Comment: @sowulo - `test.Contains("04151")`

Answer (score 1):

```
if( test == "04151" )
{
   //04151 was entered
}
```

?

If this is some type of checking a password, I would strongly urge you to do it in a safer way than checking towards a hard coded string inside your app. There are many issues with that approach. For one, you will have to recompile your program to alter your password.

Comment: Based on his comment above, I don't think that it is a password.

Comment: @John - Nope, but I was afraid it could be when I read his initial question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the other answers in the TextChanged event, to check it every time the user changes the text

Answer (score 0):

```
    public bool Matches(string test)
    {
        return String.Compare(test, "04151", true) == 0;
    }
```

Comment: you couldn't manage to make a single string comparison more difficult for a beginner? :)